# Determine potential and electric field distribution between electrodes

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrical-properties

I want to analytically determine a simplified potential and electric field distribution around planar electrodes, and an 40nm square electrode in an 50nm insulating well.

I think that the Poisson-Boltzmann equation should be appropriate but I’m unsure about a few things:

- how do I account for the presence of the stern layer?
- how do I find the electric field distribution when the potential applied is high (e.g. 2V? Where the Debye Huckel approximation cannot be used)

Cheers,
Bryan